# SIMPLE DATA COMPRESSION (DNA - binary)

Tags: java

I have a problem... I can't really understand what to do next with my task. My task is to encode the DNA code in both directions, so from string to binary and from binary to string.And DNA molecules are denoted by one of four values: A, C, G, or T. In the code A should be 00 bits, C with 01 bits, G 10 bits, and T with 11. It should look smth like this:
If the user inputs **comp CGATAAG** then the output should be **7 63 8** where 7 is symbol count.

or

If the user inputs **decomp 4 10 30 -127 32** the output should be **A 1E 81 20
ACTGGAACAG** // In decomp in needs to return value in hex and as DNA code

**I would appreciate help**

The code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MD_1 {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void comp() {

        String inp = sc.next().toUpperCase();
        int h = inp.length();
        byte[] arr = new byte[inp.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++) {
            char letter = inp.charAt(i);
            switch (letter) {
            case 'A':
                break;
            case 'C':
                break;
            case 'G':
                break;
            case 'T':
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("wrong command format");
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void decomp() {
        System.out.println("decomp is executed");
    }

    public static void about() {
        System.out.println("Author");
    }

    public static void exit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inp = "";

        while (!inp.equals("exit")) {
            inp = sc.next();
            if (inp.equals("comp")) {
                comp();
            } else if (inp.equals("decomp")) {
                decomp();
            } else if (inp.equals("about")) {
                about();
            } else if (inp.equals("exit")) {
                exit();
            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong command");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Well, my question is what to do next? I mean how to convert string to bytes and then print it out like in an example.